# Restrict Location per Domain in OpenLayers

Tags: 7, location, domain-access, javascript

I have [Domain Access](http://drupal.org/project/domain) and [Open Layers](http://drupal.org/project/openlayers) running on a site. Think of it as a map-based Craigslist. Each city has it's own subdomain, offering location-based content.

Users create content with a location on each subdomain, and I need to make sure that content's location is inside a radius (say, within 50 miles of a centerpoint) for that subdomain.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this with:

- [GeoIP API](http://drupal.org/project/geoip)
- [Context](http://drupal.org/project/context)
- [Context GeoIP](http://drupal.org/project/context_geoip)
- [Domain Context](http://drupal.org/project/domaincontext)